# SQLite Cursor caching clarification

Tags: android, sqlite

As far as I understand, a SQLite Cursor is a **snapshot** of queried data.

So, as the data is a **snapshot**, is it correct to assume that deletions/updates/iterations made by a third-party to the database, will not affect the cursor snapshot when iterating?

Since a SQLite cursor doesn't hold all the data into memory, as it loads the records when necessary while iterating, is the queried snapshot data completely isolated from the database? or will it be some illegal state situation if a third-party performs some update/delete on the records which aren't yet into memory as iteration didn't reach them yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has two ways of handling concurrent access :

- [A database lock](https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) : This is the simpler and older mechanism. Basically the lock is shared (between readers) or exclusive (held by a single writer), which means that the data can not be modified until the cursor is closed.
- [Write-Ahead Logging](https://sqlite.org/wal.html). This newer mechanism ([activated by default since Android 9](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/compatibility-wal)) allows concurrent readers and (one) writer while maintaining consistency : The cursor will retrieve the data without the changes made by later commits. From [2.2 Concurency](https://sqlite.org/wal.html#concurrency) :

> When a read operation begins on a WAL-mode database, it first
> remembers the location of the last valid commit record in the WAL.
> Call this point the "end mark". Because the WAL can be growing and
> adding new commit records while various readers connect to the
> database, each reader can potentially have its own end mark. But for
> any particular reader, the end mark is unchanged for the duration of
> the transaction, thus ensuring that **a single read transaction only
> sees the database content as it existed at a single point in time.**

The whole page is worth reading if you're interested in how SQLite works